# How to factor this quadratic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bit confused on how to factor $2x^2 + 5x − 3 = 0$. Firstly, I multiplied $a \cdot c$, so $2(-3)=-6$, however couldn't find two numbers that will add up to $5$. Then, I thought of the factors could be $6(-1)=-6$, and $6+-1=5$. However, shouldn't the $a$ and $c$ values always be multiplied together, (the $(2)(-3)$, rather than $6(-1)$?

When following the factors $-1$ and $6$.  I have

$(2x^2-1x)(6x-3)$

$x(2x-1)+3(2x-1)$

Is this correct, if not; what is the best way to solve a leading coefficient when factoring?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

We need to find two numbers with product $2(-3) = -6$ and sum $5$.  You are correct that the numbers are $-1$ and $6$.  Splitting the linear term yields
\begin{align*}
2x^2 + 5x - 3 & = 2x^2 - x + 6x - 3 && \text{split the linear term}\\
              & = x(2x - 1) + 3(2x - 1) && \text{factor by grouping}\\
              & = (x + 3)(2x - 1) && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}
which you can verify by multiplying the factors.

You should not write $(2x^2 - 1x)(6x - 3)$ since 
\begin{align*}
(2x^2 - 1x)(6x + 3) & = 2x^2(6x + 3) - 1x(6x + 3)\\
                    & = 12x^3 + 6x^2 - 6x^2 -3x\\
                    & = 12x^3 - 3x\\
                    & \neq 2x^2 + 5x - 3
\end{align*}
Instead, you can write $(2x^2 - 1x) + (6x - 3)$ or $2x^2 - 1x + 6x - 3$.

Also, you should be including equals signs since you are asserting that 
$$2x^2 + 5x - 3 = 2x^2 - x + 6x - 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes your solution is correct.

Further, note that if you know how to solve a quadratic equation, it's much more easier to factorise in those cases. Suppose the equation is $ax^2+bx+c=0$, and you can find it's roots, $x_1,x_2$. Then, you can simply write $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$$

Comment: The line $(2x^2  - 1x)(6x  + 3)$ is incorrect.

Comment: It's $+$ I think. It's a typo

Answer (score 1):

It is worth reviewing the theory behind the OP's technique.

Assume always that $a$ is a positive integer, $a \ge 1$.

Suppose

$\tag 1 ax^2+bx+c= (d_1x+e_1)(d_2x+e_2)$

where the constants $b, c, d_1. e_1, d_2 \text{ and } e_2$ are all integers.

If $\text{(1)}$ holds true then we can write

$\tag 2 ax^2+bx+c= (d_1'x+e_1')(d_2'x+e_2')$

with integer constants $d_1', e_1', d_2' \text{ and } e_2'$ such that $d_1' \text{ and } d_2'$ are both positive.

Hint: If necessary, apply  $(-1)(-1) = 1$ to the rhs of $\text{(1)}$

Now we are looking for a '$\text{(1)}$ factorization' of $2x^2 + 5x − 3$. Since $a =2$ is prime, we let $d_1 = 2$ and renaming the (unknown) constants, write,

$\tag 3 2x^2 + 5x − 3= (2x+u)(x+v)=2x^2 + (2v+u)x + uv$

Noticing that $uv = -3$ restricts things considerably, we create a google spreadsheet,

[image]

and find the answer:

$\tag 4 u = -1 \text{ and } v = 3$

so

$\tag 5 2x^2 + 5x − 3= (2x-1)(x+3)$

This technique, with the same size spreadsheet, can be used whenever both $a$ and $c$ are prime numbers. In general, you'll have to organize your work and break things down into more cases to find the solution (c.f. the [BOX METHOD](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/algebra/factoring-trinomials-using-the-box-method/)). However, the approach discussed here, can be extended and methodically applied to handle any of these problems.

Note 1: If you are lazy, just fill in the first row of the spreadsheet for the  choices available for $u$, and then use cell formulas:

[image]

Note 2: These factorization techniques can come up 'empty handed' - there may be no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^2 + 5x − 3 = 0$$

$$ac = 2(-3) = -6$$

$$\text{$^-1\times 6 =\phantom .^-6 \ $  and  $ \ ^-1+6 = 5$}$$

---

$-1$ and $6$ are correct. What you did after that is wrong.

Here are two methods that I know of for proceeding from $-1$ and $6$.

Method 1. Replace $5x$ with $-1x+6x$ and factor-by-pairing-off.

\begin{array}{c}
   2x^2 + 5x − 3 \\
   2x^2 -1x + 6x - 3 \\
   (2x^2 -1x) + (6x - 3) \\
   x(2x-1) + 3(2x-1) \\
   (x+3)(2x-1)
\end{array}

Method 2. Write out $(ax-1)(ax+6)$ and then divide out the greatest common divisors.
\begin{array}{c}
   (2x-1)(2x+6) &\{\gcd(2,-1)=1 \ \text{and} \ \gcd(2,6)=2\}\\
   \dfrac{(2x-1)}{1} \cdot \dfrac{(2x+6)}{2} \\
   (2x-1)(x+3)
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

We have that $(2x+a)(x+b)=2x^2+5x-3$, where $x=-\frac a2$ and $x=-b$ are the solutions you require.

Then $$(2x^2+(a+2b)x+ab=2x^2+5x-3$$ 
 leads to $$a+2b=5; ab=-3$$
We set $b=\frac12(5-a)\to\frac12a(5-a)=-3 \to a^2-5a-6=0$ 
$$\to a=-1, 6$$
$$\to b= 3, -\frac 12$$

So $$2x^2+5x-3=(2x-1)(x+3)=(2x+6)(x-\frac12)$$

Answer (score 0):

One could start with multiplying the polynomial with $2$ and get $$4x^2+10x-6=(2x)^2+5(2x)-6$$ which can be seen as a simple equation in $2x$ with factoring $((2x)+6)((2x)-1)$.

Taking out the added factor $2$ leaves $(x+3)(2x-1).$

For the general quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients $ax^2+bx+c$ the same approach requires the factoring of $a(ax^2+bx+c)=(ax)^2+b(ax)+ac$.

If a factoring $((ax)+m)((ax)+n)$ with integers $m$ and $n$ exists, then general theory guarantees that the extra factor $a$ can be taken out and still leave a factoring with only integer coefficients.

Comment: Nice idea. Could you expand your idea to explain how the values of $a$ and $c$ in the original polynomial relate to the coefficients of the new associated polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

So we can actually generalize this. Say we have the polynomial 
$$p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
**Fact:**
$$p(x)=\bigg(ax+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(ax+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}\bigg)$$

---

**Proof:**

Let's assume the existence of three real numbers $r_1$, $r_2$, and $e_1$ such that 
$$ax^2+bx+c=e_1(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$
If we expand the product on the right hand side and then compare coefficients,
$$ax^2+bx+c=e_1x^2-e_1(r_1+r_2)x+e_1r_1r_2$$
we get a system of equations
$$e_1=a\\-e_1(r_1+r_2)=b\\e_1r_1r_2=c$$
Evidently, we get $e_1=a$ for free. So we update our system of equations:
$$r_1+r_2=-\frac{b}{a}\\r_1r_2=\frac{c}{a}$$
We can solve each equation for $r_2$:
$$r_2=-\frac{b}{a}-r_1\\r_2=\frac{c}{ar_1}$$
So we can set the two equations equal to each-other:
$$-\frac{b}{a}-r_1=\frac{c}{ar_1}$$
$$r_1+\frac{c}{ar_1}=-\frac{b}{a}$$
multiplying both sides by $ar_1$,
$$ar_1^2+br_1=-c$$
Then we add $\frac{b^2}{4a}$ to both sides:
$$ar_1^2+br_1+\frac{b^2}{4a}=\frac{b^2}{4a}-c$$
Then we note that 
$$a(r_1+b/2a)^2=ar_1^2+br_1+\frac{b^2}{4a}$$
So we plug it in:
$$a(r_1+b/2a)^2=\frac{b^2}{4a}-c$$
$$a(r_1+b/2a)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$$
$$(r_1+b/2a)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
$$r_1+b/2a=\sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}$$
$$r_1+b/2a=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{\sqrt{4a^2}}$$
$$r_1+b/2a=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$r_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
And since we know that 
$$r_2=-\frac{b}{a}-r_1$$
We know that 
$$r_2=-\frac{b}{a}-\bigg(\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigg)$$
$$r_2=-\frac{2b}{2a}+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$r_2=\frac{b-2b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$r_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
And by definition,
$$ax^2+bx+c=a\bigg(x+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigg)\bigg(x+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\bigg)$$
$$ax^2+bx+c=\bigg(ax+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(ax+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}\bigg)$$
And with that our proof is complete :)